# Can I dismiss all the specialists after having developed everything?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I was wondering whether it would interfere with the game. I've developed all weapons.

Comment: As an alternative if you want a higher ranked researcher in that spot once you have a higher heroism rank you can redo the mission you get the specialist in and they may be a higher rank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're only required when starting development of an item, so if you've already developed everything that requires specialists, you can safely get rid of them.

It's worth noting that some specialists have unique appearances, if you care about that.

Comment: To know those,  I guess I could see the mission details for the obtainable skills. It helped a lot. Thanks. I am getting rid of them now.